# backbone and form fields

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

How to do this requirement using backbone?

**When I enter values in first text field second field must be disabled and when I delete the data from first field second field must be enabled and vice versa using backbone**

I searched many placed but have not got what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

To Enable / Disable input field in backbone as you type,you need to bind the keyup event to an event handler in your view. This can be done by adding the corresponding entry in the `events` hash.

**Binding keyup event in your Backbone Views :**

```
events : {
    "keyup #first_text" : "firstFunction",
},

// THE EVENT HANDLER FUNCTION.
firstFunction : function(e) {
    if(e.currentTarget.value && e.currentTarget.value.trim() != "") {
        $("#input_text").prop("disabled",true);
    }
    else {
        $("#input_text").prop("disabled",false);
    }
},
```

**Fiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/rnwvf3r9/

Comment: you dont need a if/else: `$("#second_text").prop("disabled",(e.currentTarget.value && e.currentTarget.value.trim() != ""));`

Comment: also, the `"disabled"` prop needs a strict boolean as the value, so you better enforce that with `!!`: `$("#second_text").prop("disabled",!!(e.currentTarget.value && e.currentTarget.value.trim() != ""));`